# How to scale resize SVG contents proportionally, using only CSSs?

Tags: css, svg, resize, scale, inline-svg

How can I scale or resize inline SVG vector artwork, **using only CSS**, so all artworks resize proportionally and fit fully into their defined width & height?

The original aspect-ratio should be respected.

In this case I would like the artwork contents to resize to 100x100px box as icons. The below snippet doesnt work, since it just seems to CROP the window instead of resizing the inner contents.

```css
svg {
  width:  100px;
  height: 100px;
  fill:   blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <polygon points="100,0 30,200 200,70 0,70 170,200"/>
</svg>

<svg >
    <polygon points="0,0 200,140 110,200"/>
</svg>

<svg>
    <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="200" ry="40" />
</svg>
```

I'm gtting this: (looks more like a crop)
[image]

But I would like to get this: (proportionally scaled to the edge of the box)
[image]

Comment: Bit rusty on this but you may need a viewBox attribute on the svg and height: auto in the CSS to keep proportions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add viewBox to keep the aspect ratio and set 100% height and width to fill the svg container.

```css
svg{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
}
svg * {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill:   blue;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 200">
  <polygon points="100,0 30,200 200,70 0,70 170,200"/>
</svg>

<svg viewbox="0 0 200 200">
  <polygon points="0,0 200,140 110,200"/>
</svg>

<svg viewbox="0 0 400 70">
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="200" ry="40" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please explain what the star `*` means in `svg *` ? So what is the difference between `svg{}` and `svg *{}` ?

Comment: Also please explain why the viewbox numbers are 200 and not 100. Is that relative to the paths they contain so in other words totally irrelated to the actual pixels to be displayed in width/height?

Comment: I wanted to include all your path so I took your highest numbers for each one. `*` in CSS is equal to 'all elements' so if you do `svg *` you are selecting all elements inside svg.